# JUnit 4.12 runs inconsistent number of tests with parallel computing

Tags: java, junit, parallel-processing

we are executing JUnit tests parallel by using a custom Computer implementation with a fixed thread pool. We noticed, that the test count drastically varies for each testrun on our ci-server (ranges from 1000 tests to 45000 tests (expected amount)).

With the ParallelComputer implementation the tests run properly, but due to a really high thread count cause other problems such as database deadlocks and server timeouts. That's why we need to limit the maximum number of threads running.

Is there another, consistent way to run JUnit tests parallel with a limited thread pool? Or is our implementation missing something?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** It seems like the cause of this behavior are test failures. As soon as any test in any thread fails the process stops without any further information. No test report is created and there is no summary of the test results.

With the default ParallelComputer, test failures are recorded but won't stop the rest of the tests from running. After all tests are run a report with all failures/errors/successes is created as expected.

Here is our implementation:

```
public class CustomParallelComputer extends Computer {

private boolean classes;
private int maxPoolSize;

public CustomParallelComputer(boolean classes, int maxPoolSize) {
    this.classes = classes;
    this.maxPoolSize = maxPoolSize;
}

public static Computer classes(int maxPoolSize) {
    return new CustomParallelComputer(true, maxPoolSize);
}

private static Runner parallelize(Runner runner, int maxPoolSize) {
    if (runner instanceof ParentRunner) {
        ((ParentRunner) runner).setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {

            private ExecutorService fService =
                    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxPoolSize);

            public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
                this.fService.submit(childStatement);
            }

            public void finished() {
                try {
                    this.fService.shutdown();
                    this.fService.awaitTermination(9223372036854775807L, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException var2) {
                    var2.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    return runner;
}

public Runner getSuite(RunnerBuilder builder,Class<?>[] classes) throws InitializationError {
   Runner suite = super.getSuite(builder, classes);
    return this.classes ? parallelize(suite, maxPoolSize) : suite;
}
}
```

We call the CustomParallelComputer from our TestSuite like this:

```
Computer classes = CustomParallelComputer.classes(maxPoolSize);
Result result = jUnitCore.run(classes, tests.toArray(new Class[tests.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the parallel processing was not the problem. 
The problem was faulty code, that caused the main thread to interrupt when called during the test run.